# Simplifying imports - performance hit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

We're using a React + Webpack setup. The traditional way to import libraries and components is something like:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Button from '../components/Button'
```

My idea is about putting all packages and components into one file. Something like this:

`/common/index.js:`

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import Button from '../components/Button'

export {React,styled,Button}
```

Then in other files, I can just do

```
import {React,styled,Button} from '../common'
```

I've been using this pattern on the server for the past few weeks. It makes importing faster (typing wise). It also gets rid of the problem that files have 10 or so imports (especially in frontend) and imports take a large part of the screen (the most valuable part of the screen...)

What do you think about this?

Are there any performance hits to doing this? I'm really assuming none, because of Webpack's magic (but I'd like to confirm this before I refactor hundreds of imports :)). Is there any other unintended consequences? Or is it just a matter of taste?

PS You might say - "Now every time I create a new component I have to import & export it in `/common/index.js`." I think you can use Webpack's native `require.context` for that. So no extra work.

Cheers!!

Comment: "*It makes importing faster [...]. It also gets rid of the problem that files have 10 or so imports [...]*" – A good IDE/editor imports modules as you type and you can collapse the import statements if they take too much screen space.